# how to read a response back from URL which is sending the response in json

Tags: php, json, url, codeigniter, response

I have been given an API url feed which returns response in JSON format and I have been told to set the headers to this:

```
Accept: application/json
X-some-API-Key: fdfdfdfdsgddc43aa96c556eb457b4009
```

Could anyone please tell me how to move ahead with this problem?

Comment: How are you making the request to the API?  Once we know that we can figure out how to set headers.

Comment: @Nick, i have no clue about that too. I dont know how to move ahead with this at all. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

I would use the [PHP curl](http://php.net/curl) libraries.

For example:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json', 
    'X-some-API-Key: fdfdfdfdsgddc43aa96c556eb457b4009',
));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

See [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information on the constants such as `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` I have used above.

### Question 2 from comments

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json', 
    'X-some-API-Key: fdfdfdfdsgddc43aa96c556eb457b4009',
));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

`$json` now contains an associative array of the response, which you can `var_dump()`to see the structure.

Comment: Ok I have got it, could you also tell me how to parse it?! I mean how to get it using some loop in php.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using cURL in PHP you can do set custom headers on the request with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'X-some-API-Key: fdfdfdfdsgddc43aa96c556eb457b4009'
));
```

Comment: thanks mate, but what is that $ch in the above code?! and how should I call the URL. My URL is this http://api.some.com/ssf?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50

Comment: @mad_programmer see my answer which includes a complete example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978090/how-to-read-a-response-back-from-url-which-is-sending-the-response-in-json/5978173#5978173